# How to use Group by with find in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have collection named "listing" with fields such as **`metadata`** and **`status`**. metadata is a object containing **`user`** object inside and **`status`** is a string.

The structure looks like this,

> {   "status": "Active",   "metadata": {
>       "user": {
>         "urlProfile": "",
>         "averageRating": 5,
>         "reviewCount": 2,
>         "userId": "1244324"
>       }   } }

Now the status field have values such as **`"Active"`** and **`"Inactive"`**. I need to group by those status and filter by the userId. so i have a function inside the helper as follows,

```
 query: function (model, conditon, options) {
            console.log(conditon, options);
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                options = options || {};

                model.find(conditon, {}, options).exec(function (error, data) {
                    if (error) {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                })
            })
        }
```

Question is how can i pass the group by along with the user id and query the data needed. Right now my querying part looks like this,

```
return dbService.query(sellerModel, {
                    'metadata.user.userId': userIdRetrieved
                }, {});
```

how can i pass the group by condition? i looked for sample, did not find any solution till now.

**Sample Collection**
[image]

**Expected Output:**

```
[{
  "Status": "Active",
  "Results": {
    "user": {
      "urlProfile": "",
      "averageRating": 5,
      "reviewCount": 2,
      "userId": "1244324"
    }
  }
}
,
{
  "Status": "InActive",
  "Results": {
    "user": {
      "urlProfile": "",
      "averageRating": 5,
      "reviewCount": 2,
      "userId": "1244324"
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: Use `aggregate`. Something like `model.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "metadata.user.userId": userIdRetrieved } },
        { "$group": { "_id": "$status", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } } 
     ])`

Comment: What's your expected output? If you could pass on some sample documents to test the aggregation, that would be great.

Comment: @Veeram i will try that ! is not there a direct way i could pass with query instead of writing a new function for groupby

Comment: @chridam updated the question with the expected output

Comment: with your current `query` you get output as you expected except `metadata` instead of `Results` below the status right ?

Comment: @Jag it does not group anything

Comment: ok. i think i didn't get it. would you mind posting your current output

Comment: @Veeram yes you are right! i will try that out! post as answer , i will mark as helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the desired output, you would need to use the **[`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** method since it offers the operators which allow you to aggregate the documents and return the said result.

Consider constructing a pipeline that consists of a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage, whereby you aggregate the average rating via the **[`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg)** accumulator, the `reviewCount` with **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** and the other fields in the group using **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)**. Your group by key is a subdocument with two fields Status and userId.

A final **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** step would allow you to reshape the output from the above group aggregates to the desired form and the **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** method returns a query which you can then call **[`exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec)** to get a [`Promise`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise).

---

To explain the above framework, follow this example:

```
query: function (model, conditon, options) {
    console.log(conditon, options);
    options = options || {};
    return model.aggregate([
        { "$match": conditon },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": { 
                    "Status": "$status", 
                    "userId": "$metadata.user.userId" 
                },
                "urlProfile": { "$first": "$metadata.user.urlProfile" },
                "averageRating": { "$avg": "$metadata.user.averageRating" },
                "reviewCount": { "$sum": "$metadata.user.reviewCount" }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "Status": "$_id.Status",
                "Results": {
                    "user": {
                        "averageRating": "$averageRating",
                        "reviewCount": "$reviewCount",
                        "userId": "$_id.userId"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]).exec();      
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chridam, i will check this out and mark as answer if it works ! thanks for your time

Comment: i am getting an error  FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo in the fields, included the reserved `$` keyword twice. For returning all the fields you can either map them one by one with `$first` or last e.g. `"urlProfile": { "$first": "$metadata.user.urlProfile" }` within the `$group` stage or use the system variable [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) which returns the root document, i.e. the top-level document with all its fields, currently being processed in the aggregation pipeline stage e.g. `"doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },`